# Python Octal to Decimal

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert octal numbers to decimal numbers, to do this I thought I would convert the octal number to binary, and then convert the binary into decimal. To do that I have written this code:

```
#test

base_8 = input("Enter octal: ")
binar = ""
if base_8 == 0:
      print("The integer value is", 0)
      
for num in reversed(base_8):
  if int(num) > 8:
      print("Invalid")
  else:
      while int(num) > 0:
          r = int(num) % 2
          num = int(num) // 2
          binar = str(r) + binar
      
         
print("Octal in binary:", binar)

decimal = 0
exponent = len(binar) - 1
for digit in binar:
  decimal = decimal + int(digit) * 2 ** exponent
  exponent = exponent - 1
print("The integer value is", decimal)
```

This works for digits above 3, however, due to how octal is converted into binary, octal numbers with digits 0-3 don't display correctly, causing the conversion to decimal to be incorrect. for example, the octal number 437 converts to 10011111, instead of 100011111, which affects the code to convert it into decimal. I've tried adding code to make it print correctly if the digit isn't above 3, however it's just ignored. Do you guys have any idea on how I could correct this?

Comment: If you just want to convert a string representing a number in octal, just pass it to `int()` using the desired base. For example `int('77',  8)`, which yields `63`.

Comment: The problem is that when converting to binary, you write only the necessary digits, such as 3 -> 11; however, for handling a base-8 conversion like that, you always need to write 3 digits, eg. 3 -> 011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick to your code you can also replace the line

```
      while int(num) > 0:
```

with

```
      for i in range(3):
```

Like this you ensure to always write three digits in binary for each digit in octal. But for anything else than code exercise I'd prefer the build in functions as well.

Comment: Thanks! I had done some other research, so I knew some other ways to do it. But I did really want to use mine for this, since I came up with it mostly on my own. So thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There are in-built functions by which you can do this -

```
onum = 324

bnum = bin(int(str(onum), 8))  # octal to binary
dec = int(bnum, 2)  # binary to decimal
```